# How to create a search bar similar to Google search style in JAVA GUI

Tags: java, swing, search, user-interface, searchbar

I am trying to create a search feature in my program similar to google search bar, where when user is typing it actually searches the database and displays the current result in a pop-out list below the `JTextField`.  I am new to java GUI programming therefore I am unclear about all the java components therefore it is hard to find suitable components which fulfil my needs, especially the component I need to use for the pop out drop down list below the text field.  I hope some experts can show me some insight.

Comment: Using layouts or you can use `Component.setBounds()` method to place them at exact position.

Comment: @VighaneshGursale I understand the part about layout manager,I am trying to figure out how do I make a pop out list or window which is only visible and appear when the user is typing on the jTextfield.

Comment: Ok so you want suggestion list. Am I right??

Comment: @VighaneshGursale Can a suggestion list appear below a textfield when user is typing and select the item inside it?

Comment: You can implement solr search ,Apache open Source.It has all the features you are looking for.

Comment: Are you using swing?

Comment: @Lokesh can you explain more in details please?I just look through their website and they have a lot of project listings,I don't know where to start from.Thank you.

Comment: @keuleJ Yes.I am using Swing

Comment: I hope this blog will give you some idea how it's been set up and used. http://kevindoran1.blogspot.com/2013/02/solr-tutorial.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SwingX API would helpful to solve this issue. You can use the following code to implement auto complete feature to editable ComboBox.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.autocomplete.AutoCompleteDecorator;
import java.awt.*;
public class Demo {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
    AutoCompleteDecorator decorator;
    JComboBox combobox;

    public Demo() {
        combobox = new JComboBox(new Object[]{"","Ester", "Jordi",
            "Jordina", "Jorge", "Sergi"});
        AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(combobox);
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        frame.add(combobox);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Demo d = new Demo();
    }
}
```

Comment: a screenshot would be more great.