# How Can we add a Google like Search box in java Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I tried some code with dynamic List in `Combobox` but after typing it does not add whole word on selected item in combobox.

How can I make it more dynamic like the Google Search Box?

Comment: You want "Auto complete". There are a few implementations, Swing Labs, SwingX library comes to mind

Comment: please refer [this link][1]. This is same doubt which u have


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26550559/how-to-create-a-search-bar-similar-to-google-search-style-in-java-gui

Answer (score 0):

You Can use this code dynamically update Combobox using Database Connection.....

```
    //code: 


String pattern=TabletCombobox.getSelectedItem().toString();
    System.out.println(pattern);
    //TabletCombobox.setSelectedItem(pattern);

    //AutoCompleteDecorator decorator;
    //AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(TabletCombobox);
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        String Query="select * from tablet";
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(Query);
        int i=1;
        while(rs.next())
        {
            TabletCombobox.add(this, rs.getString(1),i++);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
```

Comment: yaa its right but,  it will not search for content we type in editable Combo Box , so for that what to do??